# PHP pdf form parse regex

Tags: php, regex, pdf

I have a two PDF forms that I'd like to input values for using PHP.  There doesn't seem to be any open source solutions.  The only solution seems to be [SetaSign](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) which is over $400.  So instead I'm trying to dump the data as a string, parse using a regex and then save.  This is what I have so far:

```
$pdf = file_get_contents("../forms/mypdf.pdf");
$decode = utf8_decode($pdf);
$re = "/(\d+)\s(?:0 obj <>\/AP<>\/)(.*)(?:>> endobj)/U";
preg_match_all($re, $decode, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

However, **my print_r is empty even after [testing here](https://regex101.com/r/rL3mF4/1)**.  The matches on the right are first a numerical identifier for the field (I think) and then `V(XX1)` where "XX1" is the text I've manually entered into the form and saved (as a test to find how and where that data is stored).  I'm assuming (but haven't tested) that `N<>>>/AS/Off` is a checkbox.

Is there something I need to change in my regex to find matches like `(2811 0 obj <>/AP<>/V(XX2)>> endobj)` where the first find will be a key and the second find is the value?

Comment: You can't open a pdf like that. This article may help: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php

Comment: Do you only need to extract the values from a filled form or do you need to fill in the PDF form? If you only need to fill text fields the license starts at 180 EUR (~$200) instead of $400. BTW: Your quoted content is not complete as it seems that you output it to a browser, right? (view the source and you will see what I mean) Anyhow I don't think that there's a regex available that'll match all possible siutations.

Comment: I need to fill out the form.  And yes, the quoted content is not complete because of the size.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

## Part 1 - Extract text from PDF

Download the class.pdf2text.php @ http://pastebin.com/dvwySU1a (Updated on 5 of April 2014) or http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31030.html (Registration required)

Usage:

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('test.pdf'); 
$a->decodePDF();
echo $a->output();
```

The class doesn't work with all pdf's I've tested, give it a try and you may get lucky :)

## Part 2 - Write to PDF

To write the pdf contents use [tcpdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/) which is an enhanced and maintained version of fpdf.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who've looked into this.  I decided to convert the pdfs (since I'm not doing this as a batch) into svg files.  [This online converter](https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-svg-converter/) kept the form fields and with some small edits I've made them printable.  Now, I'll be able to populate the values and have a visual representation of the pdf.  I may try tcpdf in the event I want to make it an actual pdf again though I'm assuming it wont keep the form fields.